# Angular parent template `<router-outlet>` displays template twice

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-router, router-outlet, angular-routerlink

I have a parent template that its children are sharing and i am displaying that parent template in app.component.html based on some condition.

Now the issue i am facing is that parent template is displaying twice before the child component
reference picture is uploaded

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

> home.component.html

```
<div class="container register">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 register-left">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n7oTvU/logo_white.png" alt=""/>
          <h3>Welcome</h3>
          <p>You are 35 seconds away from earning your own money!</p>
          <input type="submit" name="" value="Login"/><br/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 register-right">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="myTab" role="tablist">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Employee</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Hirer</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Hirer</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
           <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
               <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                  <h3 class="register-heading">Add your project</h3>
                  <div class="row register-form">
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                  </div>
               </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

> home-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from '../../../helpers/auth.gaurd';
import { Role } from '../../../data/schema/role';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { ListProjectCategoryComponent } from '../project-folder/projectCategory/list-project-category/list-project-category.component';
import { CreateProjectCategoryComponent } from '../project-folder/projectCategory/create-project-category/create-project-category.component';
import { DetailsProjectCategoryComponent } from '../project-folder/projectCategory/details-project-category/details-project-category.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ 
  path: 'admin',
   component: HomeComponent ,
   canActivate: [AuthGuard],
data: { roles: [Role.Admin]},
children: [
{ path: 'projectCategory/list', 
component: ListProjectCategoryComponent
},
{ path: 'projectCategory/create', 
component: CreateProjectCategoryComponent
},
{ path: 'projectCategory/details', 
component: DetailsProjectCategoryComponent
}]  }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

> app.component.ts

```
<app-web-header></app-web-header>
 <div *ngIf="isAdminComponent"> 
    <app-home ></app-home> 
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isAdminComponent"> 
<app-user-home></app-user-home>
</div>
<app-web-footer></app-web-footer>
```

Here is

> app-routing-module.ts

[image]

Please do check if any other code is needed to check the issue.

Comment: Could you reproduce the error in a StackBlitz app or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Your `HomeRoutingModule` is telling Angular to use `HomeComponent`, so it is inserting it into the `router-outlet` in that very same `HomeComponent`. Remove the `admin` route and only set up the child routes and you should be good to go.

Comment: on doing so , this issue raises https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65697694/condition-based-router-outlet-not-changing-its-content-on-url-change-in-app-comp